# Degeneracy maps of Drinfeld modular curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, function-fields

Over number fields, we have two natural degeneracy maps
$$X_0(N)\leftarrow X_0(pN) \rightarrow X_0(N)$$
between the (compactified) moduli space of elliptic curves with level $pN$ and $N$ respectively (assuming furthermore that $p,N$ are coprime). In particular, we know these maps to be coverings of degree $p+1$.

My question is about the analogous situation over function fields: if $\mathfrak{p}, \mathfrak{n}\subset \mathbb{F}_p[t]$ are a prime ideal and an ideal coprime to it, then we also have two degeneracy maps between the (compactified) moduli spaces of Drinfeld modules of level $\mathfrak{pn},\mathfrak{n}$ respectively. Are these also coverings of degree $|\mathfrak{p}|+1$?